# Ways to create a mapreduce web application

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, mapreduce, cloud

I want to create a website, and part of the website I will implemented with(Hadoop mapreduce). I start using the Eclipse with maven plugin, on my operating system (Mac OS).
I start coding with apache maven for my code. "I still not implement the website".
My question does the maven run with cluster of machines or not?
any advice of how can I create a website with part run in mapreduce??

Please help
Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apahe Maven is not "something, that runs our code". It's actually a build tool: `Apache Maven is a software project management and comprehension tool.` (https://maven.apache.org/). You can manage dependencies, build, deploy and do other related stuff.

If you want some interface to your cluster, I recommend to look at **zeppelin** (https://zeppelin.apache.org/). 
It's an interpreter for a bunch of stuff and it can be easily deployed to your server (I did it by building sources from https://github.com/apache/zeppelin and running it). Zeppelin's spark interpreter can be run in yarn-client mode, which just submits your code to cluster (yarn hadoop cluster in my case) and runs it.
Seems pretty similar to your description.

The answer to your question: maven had nothing to do with "running on cluster".

Comment: @sslavia812 thanks for your replay, my case in simple, I want create a website in java, and part of the website run with mapreduce. About maven" Can i create a website with mapreduce without running it in cluster".            I have some questions to you, can i do a website using zeppelin? and can i write my code in Eclipse? , Do you have any tutorials that I can start from it? what's your code in github about?